# How to transform the irradiance image on the screen in the double-slit experiment back to electric field in order to perform Fourier Transform?

Tags: electric-fields, radiation, fourier-transform, double-slit-experiment

Say I perform the double slit experiment while meeting the requirements of the far-field. I get some interference image on the screen (where R is great, as mentioned). This image is correlated with the irradiance (I). Now I want to perform the Fourier Transform of this image so I can retrieve the dimensions of the slits.

But(!), the Fourier Transform take as input the electric field (E) at the screen, where: E^2~I. Which means, I lose the information about where the electric field is negative (comparing to the principal maxima).

When I perform iFFT on the image itself (of the irradiance) I do get the the slits (as expected) but I get another slit in the middle of the picture representing the k=0 spatial frequency, which is required to get a positive result - as is the irradiance.

I want somehow to perform the Fourier Transform of the electric field on the screen, and not of the irradiance. Is there any technical, physical, mathematical or algorithmic manner which will allow me to do so?

Thank you very much!
Yuval